# How to scrape Ajax webpage using python

Tags: python, web, screen-scraping

I am learning Python scraping technique but I am stuck with the problem of scraping an Ajax page [like this one](https://www.gianteagle.com/Pharmacy/Savings/4-10-Dollar-Drug-Program/Generic-Drug-Program/).

I want to scrape all the medicines name and details coming in the page. Since I read most of the answer on the stack overflow but I am not getting the right data after scraping. I also tried to scrape using selenium or send a forge post request but it failed.

So please help me on this Ajax scraping topic specially this page because ajax is triggered on selecting an option from dropdown options.
Also please provide me with some resources for ajax page scraping.

//using selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
import bs4 as bs
import lxml
import requests

path_to_chrome = '/home/brutal/Desktop/chromedriver'

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chrome)

url = 'https://www.gianteagle.com/Pharmacy/Savings/4-10-Dollar-Drug-Program/Generic-Drug-Program/'

browser.get(url)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_RegionPage_RegionPageMainContent_RegionPageContent_userControl_StateList"]/option[contains(text(), "Ohio")]').click()

new_url = browser.current_url
r = requests.get(new_url)
print(r.content)
```

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried with selenium for instance ?

Comment: I tried to trigger the city option so that the new ajax page load and i can go through the url and get the medicine table data but since the page load with the same url i got the scrap data but without the info i need

Comment: you should provide some code

Comment: please add your code in the question, not in comments

Comment: @Abhinavrawat, Do you want to get all names and its data for each state? Correct?

Comment: Yup all data related to medicines in each city

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ChromeDriver you can download [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.25/)

`normalize-space` is used in order to remove trash from web text, such as `x0`

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from lxml.html import fromstring

data = {}

driver = webdriver.Chrome('PATH TO YOUR DRIVER/chromedriver')  # i.e '/home/superman/www/myproject/chromedriver'
driver.get('https://www.gianteagle.com/Pharmacy/Savings/4-10-Dollar-Drug-Program/Generic-Drug-Program/')

# Loop states
for i in range(2, 7):
    dropdown_state = driver.find_element(by='id', value='ctl00_RegionPage_RegionPageMainContent_RegionPageContent_userControl_StateList')

    # open dropdown
    dropdown_state.click()

    # click state
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_RegionPage_RegionPageMainContent_RegionPageContent_userControl_StateList"]/option['+str(i)+']').click()

    # let download the page
    sleep(3)

    # prepare HTML
    page_content = driver.page_source
    tree = fromstring(page_content)

    state = tree.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_RegionPage_RegionPageMainContent_RegionPageContent_userControl_StateList"]/option['+str(i)+']/text()')[0]
    data[state] = []

    # Loop products inside the state
    for line in tree.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_RegionPage_RegionPageMainContent_RegionPageContent_userControl_gridSearchResults"]/tbody/tr[@style]'):
        med_type = line.xpath('normalize-space(.//td[@class="medication-type"])')
        generic_name = line.xpath('normalize-space(.//td[@class="generic-name"])')

        brand_name = line.xpath('normalize-space(.//td[@class="brand-name hidden-xs"])')
        strength = line.xpath('normalize-space(.//td[@class="strength"])')
        form = line.xpath('normalize-space(.//td[@class="form"])')

        qty_30_day = line.xpath('normalize-space(.//td[@class="30-qty"])')
        price_30_day = line.xpath('normalize-space(.//td[@class="30-price"])')

        qty_90_day = line.xpath('normalize-space(.//td[@class="90-qty hidden-xs"])')
        price_90_day = line.xpath('normalize-space(.//td[@class="90-price hidden-xs"])')

        data[state].append(dict(med_type=med_type,
                                generic_name=generic_name,
                                brand_name=brand_name,
                                strength=strength,
                                form=form,
                                qty_30_day=qty_30_day,
                                price_30_day=price_30_day,
                                qty_90_day=qty_90_day,
                                price_90_day=price_90_day))

print('data:', data)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you very much . Can u just tell me why there [0] at the end of this line                                                                                                             

 state = tree.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_RegionPage_RegionPageMainContent_RegionPageContent_userControl_StateList"]/option['+str(i)+']/text()')[0]

Comment: @Abhinavrawat, because `tree.xpath` in this case (when do not use `normalize-space`) returns list, i.e ['Ohio'] for example. Using [0] I am exctracting the value from the list, because we do not need list - we need actual value :). Do not forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: k thanx once again

Comment: @Abhinavrawat, I would appreciate if you could accept the answer (under the 2 up\down arrows in front of my answer there is a grey check mark). Thank you.